# Solving bugs in javascript - Tab functionality

Tags: javascript, tabs

Link to project: http://bayer.grafikomudv.dk/tester/

I have a few bugs on the site, that I can't figure out on how to solve..

Bug 1: When I click one of the icons for the first time (after the page is loaded) it quickly unfolds and folds back up. I need it to just unfold, and stay open.

Bug 2: When I have on tab open, and click on another one, it closes. And I have to press the tab again to open it. I want it to unfold when clicking once.

Anybody who can point me in the right direction on how to solve these to bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Please use

e.preventDefault();

in your bind event function..

It will be good if your post full code so that i can give you more clear answer.